# How to include asp.net mvc "Sections" in bundles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

I have in my page various sections of scripts because i like to keep my html and javascript in the same file.How can i include the "Section scripts in the bundle"?

Comment: Can you show some code examples

Comment: Since bundling doesn't relay on routing. Yours bundling file can refer the required script files across various areas, without any issue.

Comment: I suspect you might be confused by `bundles` and `sections`. Post some code you have tried.